# Trouble with nested imports in python

Tags: python, import

I am writing a project in python and have been having major trouble with imports. My project consists of a number of scripts, and I have been trying to write a gui that will allow the user to run any of the scripts on demand. In order to do this, I have created a directory for the scripts, with a sub-directory for each specific script. I have a seperate directory called gui, with a python file that is meant to import each script and run it. The file structure is as follows.

```
scripts/  
       script1/  
              file1.py  
              file2.py  
              main.py  
gui/  
   gui.py
```

In the gui.py file I have:

```
from scripts.script1.main import main as script1
```

and in the main.py file I have:

```
from file1 import function1  
from file2 import function2
```

When I run the gui.py file, main.py is imported as intended, but I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file1'
```

whenever I run the code.
I'm not really sure why this happens and how to fix it. If I print sys.path it includes the root directory for the project, but none of the subdirectories. What's happening here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I changed the nested imports to:

```
from .file1 import function1
from .file2 import function2
```

This works. I still do not understand why.

Comment: you have specific folders that are searched for files that you try to import. you can either use `from scripts.script1.file1 ...`   or `from .file1 ....` (this one only works if current file is located in the same directory as the import)

Answer (score -1):

Hi you must make the python file and import it in your main file

Comment: So you can use the every things from imported  file like clash object